# Is C++20 lazy_split_view overconstrained Pattern when V is an input_range?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, c++23

In [[range.lazy.split.view]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.lazy.split.view), the synopsis of `lazy_split_view` (the original C++20 `split_view` before [P2210](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2210r2.html)) is defined as follows:

```
template<input_­range V, forward_­range Pattern>
    requires view<V> && view<Pattern> &&                
             (forward_­range<V> || tiny-range<Pattern>)
class lazy_split_view : public view_interface<lazy_split_view<V, Pattern>> {
private:
  V base_ = V();
  Pattern pattern_ = Pattern();
  // ...
};
```

Unlike the redesigned [`split_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view), it *can* split `input_range`. According to its constraints, we can find that when `V` is `input_range`, the `Pattern` must model *`tiny-range`*, where *`tiny-range`* is defined as follows:

```
template<auto> struct require-constant;

template<class R>
concept tiny-range =
  sized_­range<R> &&
  requires { typename require-constant<remove_reference_t<R>::size()>; } &&
  (remove_reference_t<R>::size() <= 1);
```

In order to ensure that the size of *`tiny-range`* is less than or equal to `1` *at compile-time*, we must obtain the size of `R` through its type, which also requires the `size()` function of `R` to be a `constexpr` `static` function.

And in the standard, there are indeed range type that model *`tiny-range`* such as `empty_view` and `single_view` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jf6WM1fbb)):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  auto ints = std::istringstream{"42"};
  auto r = std::ranges::istream_view<int>(ints);
  auto s1 = r | std::views::lazy_split(std::views::empty<int>);
  auto s2 = r | std::views::lazy_split(std::views::single(0));
}
```

But in my opinion, when `V` is `input_range`, `std::array<int, 1>`, `span<int, 1>` or even `int[1]` can be valid `Pattern` types, because we can also directly extract their size from the type, but none of the three have a `static size()` function, which makes them unable to model *`tiny_range`*.

In addition, because of the existence of the following CTAD:

```
template<class R, class P>
lazy_split_view(R&&, P&&) -> lazy_split_view<views::all_t<R>, views::all_t<P>>;
```

When `V` is an `input_range`, the `Pattern` can *never* be a non-`view` range, because [`views::all_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/all_view) will produce `ref_view` or `owning_view`, neither of which is *`tiny-range`* even `Pattern` itself may model *`tiny-range`* ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/34PaKbW1z)):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <stream>
#include <array>

int main() {
  auto ints = std::istringstream{"42"};
  auto r = std::ranges::istream_view<int>(ints);
  std::array p{42};
  r | std::views::lazy_split(p);  // ref_view<array<int, 1>> is not tiny-range 
  r | std::views::lazy_split(std::span{p}); // span<int, 1>> is not tiny-range
}
```

In summary, the definition of *`tiny-range`* seems to limit the type of `Pattern` range to a very *small* set when `V` is an `input_range`. What is the reason for such restriction in the standard?

Comment: C++20 has no `lazy_split_view`.

Comment: @NicolBolas `lazy_split_view` comes from [P2210](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2210r2.html) which is a C++20 DR (not a C++23 proposal), that is to say, after P2210 is implemented, `-std=c++20` *can* guarantee `lazy_split_view`. Why do you say that it does not come from C++20?